# Delphi - join 2 integer in a Int64

Tags: delphi, assembly, strcat, rdtsc

I'm working with `Delphi` and `Assembly`, so, i had a problem. I used a instruction(`RDTSC`) in Assembly of getting a 64-bits read time-stamp, the instruction put the numbers separately in two registers `EAX` and `EDX`. But it's ok, i get it with `Delphi Integer` variables. But now, i need to join those variables in 1 of 64-bits. It's like:

```
Var1 = 46523
var2 = 1236
```

So i need to put it into one variable like:

```
Var3 = 465231236
```

it's like a StrCat, but i'm don't know how to do it. Somebody can help me?

Comment: `(46523 << 32) | 1236` does not equal 465231236.

Comment: Your question and your sample is not the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You certainly don't want to concatenate the decimal string representations of the two values. That is not the way you are expected to combine the two 32 bit values returned from `RTDSC` into a 64 bit value.

Combining 46523 and 1236 should not yield 465231236. That is the wrong answer. Instead, you want to take the high order 32 bits, and put them alongside the low order 32 bits.

You are combining `$0000B5BB` and `$00004D4`. The correct answer is either `$0000B5BB00004D4` or `$00004D40000B5BB`, depending on which of the two values are the high and low order parts.

Implement this in code, for instance, using [`Int64Rec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Int64Rec):

```
var
  Value: UInt64;
...
Int64Rec(Value).Lo := Lo;
Int64Rec(Value).Hi := Hi;
```

where `Lo` and `Hi` are the low and high 32 bit values returned by `RTDSC`.

So, bits 0 to 31 are set to the value of `Lo`, and bits 32 to 63 are set to the value of `Hi`.

Or it can be written using bitwise operations:

```
Value := (UInt64(Hi) shl 32) or UInt64(Lo);
```

If all you need to do is read the time stamp counter, then you don't need to do any of this though. You can implement the function like this:

```
function TimeStampCounter: UInt64;
asm
  RDTSC
end;
```

The register calling convention requires that a 64 bit value return value is passed back to the caller in `EDX:EAX`. Since the `RDTSC` places the values in those exact registers (not a coincidence by the way), you have nothing more to do.

All of this said, rather than using the time stamp counter, it is usually preferable to use the performance counter, which is wrapped by [`TStopWatch`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) from [`System.Diagnostics`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Diagnostics).

Answer (score 6):

The simple way is to use a record

```
type
  TMyTimestamp = record
    case Boolean of
      true:
        ( Value: Int64 );
      false:
        ( Value1: Integer; Value2: Integer );
  end;
```

and you can store/read each value as you like

```
var
  ts: TMyTimestamp;
begin
  ts.Value1 := 46523;
  ts.Value2 := 1236;
  WriteLn( ts.Value ); // -> 5308579624379

  ts.Value := 5308579624379;
  WriteLn( ts.Value1 ); // -> 46523
  WriteLn( ts.Value2 ); // -> 1236
end;
```

see: [Docwiki: Variant Parts in Records](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records)